# Action queue in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Because I needed to execute some actions one by one in seperate thread (not to block GUI) and I couldn't use `Task.ContinueWith` from .NET 4.0 I decided to write it by myself.

Here is how it evolved thanks to your suggestions.

```
public class ActionQueue
{
    private Thread _thread;
    private bool _isProcessed = false;
    private object _queueSync = new object();
    private readonly Queue<Action> _actions = new Queue<Action>();
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when one of executed action throws unhandled exception.
    /// </summary>
    public event CrossThreadExceptionEventHandler ExceptionOccured;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when all actions in queue are finished.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ProcessingFinished;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets enqueued actions.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Action> Actions
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_queueSync)
            {
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<Action>(_actions.ToList());
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Execute()
    {
        _isProcessed = true;

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Action action = null;

                lock (_queueSync)
                {
                    if (_actions.Count == 0)
                        break;
                    else
                        action = _actions.Dequeue();
                }

                action.Invoke();
            }

            if (ProcessingFinished != null)
            {
                _context.Send(s => ProcessingFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty), null);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // Execution aborted
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ExceptionOccured != null)
            {
                _context.Send(s => ExceptionOccured(this, new CrossThreadExceptionEventArgs(ex)), null);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isProcessed = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts processing current queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns true if execution was started.</returns>
    public virtual bool Process()
    {
        if (!_isProcessed)
        {
            _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            _thread = new Thread(Execute);
            _thread.Start();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enqueues action to process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">Action to enqueue.</param>
    public void Enqueue(Action action)
    {
        lock (_queueSync)
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(action);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears queue.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_queueSync)
        {
            _actions.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Aborts execution of current queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns true if execution was aborted.</returns>
    public bool Abort()
    {
        if (_isProcessed)
        {
            _thread.Abort();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public delegate void CrossThreadExceptionEventHandler(object sender, CrossThreadExceptionEventArgs e);

public class CrossThreadExceptionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CrossThreadExceptionEventArgs(Exception exception)
    {
        this.Exception = exception;
    }

    public Exception Exception
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here is some usage example:

```
ActionQueue queue = new ActionQueue();

queue.Enqueue(SomeMethod);
queue.Process();

foreach(var item in collection)
{
    var itemToProcess = item;
    queue.Enqueue(() => SomeMethod(itemToProcess));
}

queue.Process();
```

Edits:

- Implemented observable pattern
- Synchronization context added
- `IsProcessed` property removed

Answer (score 4):

Since the class itself does very little (runs a bunch of methods on a separate thread), there is little justification in using it, IMHO.

This statement would basically do the same thing (on a `ThreadPool`, that is):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
{
    SomeMethod();
    DoSomething();
    AndSomeMore();
});
```

If it included stuff like progress updating, exception handling and finalization events, then it could make more sense to use it:

```
interface IActionQueue
{
    void Start();

    // if you know the list count, you can provide some progress info
    event Action<Double> ProgressChanged;

    // there is no way to catch an exception on a separate thread, so 
    // this would be neat
    event Action<Exception> ExceptionHappened;

    // this can be useful also
    event Action Finished;
}
```

Comment: I think that justification in using it is the possibility to reuse it and expand in the future. You think that isn't enough? :)

Comment: And I thought that `ThreadPool` is used rather to do some work in parallel. Am I wrong? Does it execute actions one by one?

Comment: Oh, sorry - now I see that you put it in a single lambda :) You are right then. Thank you.

Comment: But wait... I need to enqueue some actions from different places and in different moments and then start them from another so the code you provided is not enough. Of course, I can build a queue and process it using `ThreadPool` but don't you think that using `ActionQueue` is better idea?

Comment: @rotman: ok, my answer was based on your first example. If you do need to create this list from several places, using a separate class might make it more explicit. But you should then consider suggestions made by Slade and Jesse: I would not expose the mutable list to the outside world, if there is a chance that it may be iterated on a separate thread. The simplest way would be to change the list into a `Queue`, make it private, and expose a public `Add` method which should *lock* while enqueuing.

Comment: New version above.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not ThreadSafe, replace the Queue with ConcurrentQueue or add locking around all the Enqueue, Dequeue, and Count members. Also, I would avoid throwing an exception if the Queue is still processing. This condition is something that is largely a private concern of your class.

Comment: I can't use `ConcurrentQueue` because it's .NET 3.5 so I introduced locks. Thanks for that.

Maybe throwing exception it's the best solution (do you have any suggestions?) but I rather disagree that state of being processed is a private concern of the class. What if some other object wants to check if queue has ended the work? I can imagine such situation.

Comment: In both cases where your throwing an exception I would just exit silently. Although I don't have the full context, it just seems like the caller shouldn't need to the know about the inner workings of this class; at least not at that level. Having said that, if the caller needs to be aware of whether or not their invokation led to the initiation of any real action, you could simply return with a bool or enum indicating what they triggered; if anything.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer one of your questions. If callers need to be notified when a queued item is processed, there are more efficient ways of achieving this. For example, you could use an Observer Pattern and let callers subscribe to the working state of the Queue (Ex. OnProcessingQueuedItems, OnQueuedItemProcessed, OnProcessingQueueCompleted, etc...). Alternatively, each caller could register a callback with the request and be notified when their instance is processed. In any case, using exceptions such as I saw above just isn't a great way to communicate what you've indicated

Comment: I totally agreed with your suggestions. I can find updated version above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `ActionQueue` simply for invoking a collection of actions one-by-one one another thread, then there isn't really much you can say over the implementation (other than the point already made by Groo).

However, if you wish to have this `ActionQueue` running on another thread, while accepting requests to queue another action to execute (so you can execute actions asynchronously), then you may wish to look into using a combination of [`Queue<Action>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), a background worker thread and [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). I won't write the full implementation of that here, as I don't know if that is what you want, but if you do then I would be happy to edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expose your concrete lists:

```
public class ActionQueue
{
    private readonly IList<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    public IEnumerable<Action> Actions
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<Action>(actions);
        }
    }

    public void Add(Action action)
    {
        this.actions.Add(action);
    }

    protected virtual void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var action in this.actions)
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Execute);

        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `IList` interface in this case if you are wanting to restrict access to the `Actions` property. Instead, I'd maintain it as `List` inside of the `class` and change the return type of the `Actions` property to `IEnumerable<Action>`. Then still use the `ReadOnlyCollection<Action>`.

Comment: I'll buy that..

Comment: I took into account your suggestions. New version above.